# How to get (in PHP) all substrings, which describes a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm creating regular expression in the form: **A | B | C ...** automatically, by program, 
where **A, B, C, ...** are constant strings.

I need to find all the matches that correspond to these regular expression, 
even if the **A, B, C, ...** have **not  empty intersection**, or someone **is substring** of other.

Example:

```
preg_match_all ('/Hello World|Hello|World lo/i', 'xxxHello worldxxx', $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER); 
var_export ($m);
```

It gives:

```
array (
   0 =>
   array (
     0 =>
     array (
       0 => 'Hello World'
       1 => 3, // start of match
     )
   )
)
```

I would need:

```
array (
   0 =>
   array (
     0 =>
     array (
       0 => 'Hello World'
       1 => 3, // start of match
     )
     1 =>
     array (
       0 => 'Hello'
       1 => 3, // start of match
     )
     2 =>
     array (
       0 => 'lo world'
       1 => 6, // start of match
     )
   )
)
```

**Is there any way to get it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Run a `preg_match_all` for each expression.

Comment: Thank you. It is possible. But I'm trying to find a quicker solution. I would, that the "parser" does not pass text too often. I am considering looking for a groups of keywords, where in one group no keyword will be substring of another. Then it was applied to each group preg_match_all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use strpos:

```
$str = 'xxxHello worldxxx';
$arr = array('Hello World', 'Hello', 'World');
foreach($arr as $word) {
    $pos = strpos(strtolower($str), strtolower($word));
    echo "$word found at char $pos\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
Hello World found at char 3
Hello found at char 3
World found at char 9
```